# BLE with iOS Advertising Interval

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, nrf51

I have established a connection between an nRF52 which has the advertising interval set at 20ms and iOS software, but the packages are only received every second roughly. Has anyone had this issue before/knows any tricks to speed up the frequency? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its depending on nRF52 or other peripheral advertising interval in firmware. Also depends on data/packets transfer speed/distance.

If there is write characteristic available on peripheral for set time, then send/write values and speed up for this. Some device has this property for advertising interval time set but iOS/Android app.